# How to change Root path of HTTP server of marklogic project using mlgradle?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, ml-gradle

I need to change the root path of Appserver in marklogic using mlgradle. Can I know how to do it?

Is there any way to do such changes using mlgradle?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need a file under src/main/ml-config/servers - it can have any filename, e.g. BuildAutomation.json - with a "server-name" property (so ml-gradle knows what server it applies to) and a "root" property.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a little on what @rjrudin said, in my project, I have a server config file in src/main/ml-config/servers that includes the following:

```
{
  "server-name": "myServer",
  "group-name": "Default",
  "server-type": "http",
  "enabled": true,
  "root": "%%myServerRoot%%",
  "port": %%myServerPort%%,
  ...
}
```

And then I define `myServerRoot` and `myServerPort` in my gradle properties file. You could, of course, hard code the values, too, but I wanted more deployment flexibility in my project.